# Sampling from multivariate truncated normal

Tags: r, sampling, normal-distribution, truncated

I try to implement [this procedure](https://pdfhost.io/v/mtUFt5CPS_document) with the following r code by using package TruncatedNormal:

```
# Setup
set.seed(1) 
d = 3
Sigma = matrix(rWishart(1, d, diag(16,d)), d)/d
l = rcauchy(d)
cholSigma = t(chol(Sigma))
nsim = 1e+6

# Create matrix x and update x based on formula in link
x = matrix(nrow = d, ncol = nsim)
x[1,] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n = nsim, mu = 0, sd = 1, 
                                 lb = -l[1]/cholSigma[1,1], ub = +Inf)
for(i in 2:d){
  x[i,] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n = 1, mu = 0, sd = 1, 
                                  lb = -(l[i] + cholSigma[i,1:(i-1)] %*% x[1:(i-1),]) / cholSigma[i,i], 
                                  ub = rep(+Inf, nsim))
}

y0 = cholSigma%*%x
```

I report the values of Sigma and l.

```
Sigma
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  5.031011  6.591142 -4.809947
[2,]  6.591142 28.714024 -9.351387
[3,] -4.809947 -9.351387  5.118928

l
[1] 138.34760311  -1.22737450  -0.02543323
```

Also I use the function `mvrandn` for sampling from multivariate truncated normal in order to compare the results.

```
y1 = TruncatedNormal::mvrandn(l = -l, u = rep(+Inf, d), Sig = Sigma, n = nsim)
```

So I obtaing the following empirical mean:

```
rowMeans(y0)
[1] 9.933312e-05 4.569716e+00 5.042449e-01

rowMeans(y1)
[1] -1.7249942  3.1711154  0.8770725
```

But I do one million of draws, so I think something is wrong in my algorithm since there are large differences in the mean estimator. What is the problem?

Thanks for the help.

Edit @timm: thank you for the answer. If I understand, nothing seems to have changed, indeed

```
# Setup
set.seed(1)
d = 3
Sigma = matrix(rWishart(1, d, diag(16,d)), d)/d
l = rcauchy(d)
cholSigma = t(chol(Sigma))

nsim = 1e+6
Create matrix x and update x based on formula in link
#x = matrix(nrow = d, ncol = nsim)
x = matrix(nrow = nsim, ncol = d)

#x[1,] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n = nsim, mu = 0, sd = 1,
 #lb = -l[1]/cholSigma[1,1], ub = +Inf)
x[,1] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n = nsim, mu = 0, sd = 1,
 lb = -l[1]/cholSigma[1,1], ub = +Inf)

for(i in 2:d){

  #x[i,] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n = 1, mu = 0, sd = 1,
 #lb = -(l[i] + cholSigma[i,1:(i-1)]%*%x[1:(i-1),])/cholSigma[i,i],
 #ub = rep(+Inf,nsim))

  x[,i] = TruncatedNormal::rtnorm(n= 1, mu = 0, sd = 1,
 lb = -(l[i] + cholSigma[i,1:(i-1)]%*%t(x[,1:(i-1)]))/cholSigma[i,i],
 ub = rep(+Inf,nsim))

}

#y0 = cholSigma%*%x
y0 = cholSigma%*%t(x)

y1 = TruncatedNormal::mvrandn(l = -l, u = rep(+Inf, d), Sig = Sigma, n = nsim)

rowMeans(y0)
[1] 9.933312e-05 4.569716e+00 5.042449e-01
rowMeans(y1)
[1] -1.7249942  3.1711154  0.8770725
```

Comment: I think you just have to switch the column and the row of your ```x``` matrix and adapt the subsequent code accordingly. So ```nrow = nsim, ncol = d```.

Comment: ```-l[1]/cholSigma[1,1]``` is the upper bound in ```rtnorm```, right? For columns two and three of ```x``` you seem to impose another upper limit if I'm not mistaken. Why?

Comment: `-l[1]/cholSigma[1,1]` is the lower bound in `rtnorm`. In columns two and three I impose a different lower limit because I sample from [this conditional distribution](https://i.postimg.cc/Dy6FrK6k/img.png). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. Where did you get the last formula in the linked document from?

Comment: In the linked document there are my mathematical steps, but I think the same representation via Cholesky decomposition can be find in many papers in literature, for instance in this [paper](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/mvn.pdf) at the beginning of page 2 there is the same representation used in the context of numerical approximation of multiple gaussian integral. Thank you for the help again.